# when use libxdo, it raise "error: unknown type name ‘useconds_t’"

Tags: c, linux, cmake, xdotool

here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -std=c11")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
add_executable(ex ex.c)
target_link_libraries(ex xdo)
```

the full code is [here](https://gist.github.com/roroco/5100fce8f9799626f9e5)

of course, the libxdo.so and xdo.h is exist

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I find the reason, `useconds_t` in "unistd.h", but it require first use `#define __USE_XOPEN`, the right code is

```
#include "unistd.h"
#define __USE_XOPEN
#include <xdo.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

the checked answer is wrong, the right solution is:

```
#define __USE_XOPEN
#include "unistd.h"
#include <xdo.h>
```